# Create an instance of an object using an Expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, lambda

I have this class

```
public class TableSettings
{

    public string TableCssClass
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string EditAction
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

and I want to be able to send an instance of this object via parameters doing something like this:

```
, tableSettings => {
        tableSettings.TableCssClass = "table";
        tableSettings.EditAction = "action";
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "send an instance of this object"? What is that snippet part of? The question is missing a huge heap of context at the moment. (The `TableSettings` class would also be much shorter with `{ get; set; }` style autoproperties, helping us to focus on the important information in the question - which is currently missing.)

Comment: Fundamentally, if you create a method with a parameter of type `Action<TableSettings>` then the code in the second part of your question will work. But we've no idea whether you're able to specify the method parameters, or what - because you've given us no context.

Comment: Lambdas like these are used to configure already created objects, not create new instances. When you see eg `.AddLogging(builder=>{ builder.Level = LogLevel.Warning;})` in ASP.NET Core examples, the `builder` instance is created inside `AddLogging`. The lambda is used to set that object's properties

Comment: You're right, I'm trying to create a Html Helper for table creation, and I want to have a settings object like that one, to manage things like cssClass or Id, I will try this `Action<TableSettings>`, thanks for the quick answer @JonSkeet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This lambda isn't creating an object.

Lambdas like these are used to configure already created objects, not create new instances. When you see code like this in a .NET Core example, the `logging` instance is created inside `AddLogging` itself :

```
services.AddLogging(logging => 
    {
        logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Warning)
               .AddConsole();
    })
```

If you check the source code for [AddLogging](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/src/LoggingServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L32) you'll see it creates a new `LoggingBuilder` instance and passes it as an argument to the lambda :

```
public static IServiceCollection AddLogging(this IServiceCollection services, 
        Action<ILoggingBuilder> configure)
{
   ...
   configure(new LoggingBuilder(services));
   return services;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use a lambda to create an Object? You can just construct objects like in the following example.

```
, new ObjectName {
    Property1 = value1,
    Property2 = value2
});
```